# Is there a (semantic) difference between the return value of placement new and the casted value of its operand?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing, placement-new

Is there a (semantic) difference between the return value of placement new and the casted value of its operand?

```
struct Foo { ... };
char buffer[...];

Foo *a = new(buffer) Foo;
Foo *b = reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(buffer);
```

Does `a` and `b` differ in some way?

---

EDIT: Based on DaBler's comment, this question tells that there is a difference, if const/reference members used: [Placement new and assignment of class with const member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473621/placement-new-and-assignment-of-class-with-const-member)

So, my little-bit updated question: Does `a` and `b` differ in any way, if `Foo` doesn't have const or reference members?

Comment: new(buffer) Foo; will call the constructor of the object; the other does not.

Comment: @UKMonkey: sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Both lines are run, first the placement new, and then the cast.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference if the class contains const members. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473621/placement-new-and-assignment-of-class-with-const-member) for details.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Only `a` can safely be used to directly access the `Foo` object created by the placement *new-expression* (which we'll call `x` for ease of reference). Using `b` requires `std::launder`.

The value of `a` is specified in [[expr.new]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.new#1.sentence-7):

> If the entity is a non-array object, the result of the *new-expression*
>   is a pointer to the object created.

The value of `a` is therefore "pointer to `x`". This pointer, of course, can safely be used to access `x`.

`reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(buffer)` applies the array-to-pointer conversion to `buffer` (see [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#1.sentence-2)). The resulting value after the conversion is applied is "pointer to the first element of `buffer`". 
This is a `reinterpret_cast` of an object pointer to an object pointer of a different type, and is defined as equivalent to `static_cast<Foo*>(static_cast<void*>(buffer))` by [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#7.sentence-2).

The inner cast to `void*` is actually an implicit conversion. Per [[conv.ptr]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.ptr#2),

> The pointer value is unchanged by this conversion.

Therefore the inner cast yields a `void*` with the value "pointer to the first element of `buffer`".

The outer cast is governed by [[expr.static.cast]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#13), which I've lightly reformatted into bullet points:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `void`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* `T`”, where `T` is an object type and *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*.
>
> - If the original pointer value represents the address `A` of a byte in memory and `A` does not satisfy the alignment requirement of `T`,
>     then the resulting pointer value is unspecified.
> - Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an object `a`, and there is an object `b` of type `T` (ignoring cv-qualification)
>     that is pointer-interconvertible with `a`, the result is a pointer to
>     `b`.
> - Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

Assuming that `buffer` is suitably aligned (you'd be in trouble well before this point if it's not), the first bullet is inapplicable. The second bullet is likewise inapplicable as there's no [pointer-interconvertiblity](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.compound#4) here. It follows that we hit the third bullet - "the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion" and remains "pointer to the first element of `buffer`".

Thus, `b` does not point to the `Foo` object `x`; it points instead to the first `char` element of `buffer`, even though its type is `Foo*`. It therefore cannot be used to access `x`; attempting to do so yields undefined behavior (for the non-static data member case, by omission from [[expr.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ref#4.2); for the non-static member function case, by [[class.mfct.non-static]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mfct.non-static#2)).

To recover a pointer to `x` from `b`, `std::launder` can be used:

```
b = std::launder(b); // value of b is now "pointer to x"
                     // and can be used to access x
```

Answer (score 5):

Access through `a` is legal while `b` is not. From [[basic.compound]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#4)

> Two objects `a` and `b` are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> - they are the same object, or
> - one is a standard-layout union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object, or
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, the first base class subobject of that object ([class.mem]), or
> - there exists an object `c` such that `a` and `c` are pointer-interconvertible, and `c` and `b` are pointer-interconvertible.
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`. [ Note: An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address.  — end note ]

They are not the same object, not unions and not subobjects to each other, therefore not pointer-interconvertible.

Note [[expr.reinterpret.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) only guarantees `reinterpret_cast<char*>(b) == buffer`.

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to `cv T`”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`. [ Note: Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value.  — end note ]