# Object access through an unsigned char alias, what happens on load and on store?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, strict-aliasing

In the following example, the array is not accessed through its first element but by what is conceptually an alias of the array. Nevertheless, accordingly to C++17/[[basic.lval]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8) the stored value of an object can be accessed through an unsigned char. So is it right to think that the following assertion will never fire?

```
void g(){
  unsigned char s[]={'X'};
  unsigned char (*pointer_to_array_s)[1] = &s;
  unsigned char *alias_to_array_s = 
      reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pointer_to_array_s);
  //alias_to_array_s is not a pointer whose value point to c[0] because an array 
  //and its firts element are not pointer interconvertible see [basic.compound]
  //*alias_to_array_s aliases s;
  assert(*alias_to_array_s=='X'); //may fire?
  }
```

The fact the `alias_to_array_s` is not a valid pointer to the first element of `s` is due to a subtlety introduced in C++17, see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062346/is-a-pointer-with-the-right-address-and-type-still-always-a-valid-pointer-since).

Now let's suppose that I modify the array through the alias, can I retrieve this modification by directly accessing the array?

```
void g(){
  unsigned char s[]={'X'};
  unsigned char (*pointer_to_array_s)[1] = &s;
  unsigned char *alias_to_array_s = 
      reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pointer_to_array_s);
  *alias_to_array_s='Y'; //UB?
  assert(s[0]=='Y');//may fire?
  }
```

Comment: That cast is not necessary: `unsigned char *alias_to_array_s = *pointer_to_array_s;`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - That's not the point of the question.

Comment: There is small, but essential difference to the question you referred to: You are not incrementing the address, thus never getting to the past the end pointer!

Comment: An array object is still an object. Accessing an object through a `unsigned char` is always well-defined. The [pointer still points to the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164192/4832499), but accessing through it is fine

Comment: @StoryTeller But if your remove the unnecessary cast there is no longer the question.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - This is a question about the intricate rules governing the language, not a "how to make it work" question. So, again, not the point.

Comment: @PasserBy, accessing is ok, but what can be asserted about the value? And for exemple I make a store through the object name, then a store through the aliasing pointer and then a load through the object name, is there no risk the compiler optimize away the last load and reflect it by an immediate which would equal the first store?

Comment: Since `unsigned char*` `char*` `std::byte*` is allowed to alias anything, the compiler can't optimize that away. The standard doesn't actually say anything about aliasing and optimizing. It only says under what conditions can an object be modified. If the conditions are met, the object is modified and your compiler must do that too

Comment: And because for C-style arrays the pointer to the array points to the first element, modifying the first byte of the object representation through the types @PasserBy listed is guaranteed to modify the first byte of the first element of the array.

Comment: Possible related discussion: [What is the semantics for exceptions for strict aliasing rules?](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-discussion/hp78s03Dxe4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> accessing is ok, but what can be asserted about the value? And for
>   exemple I make a store through the object name, then a store through
>   the aliasing pointer and then a load through the object name, is there
>   no risk the compiler optimize away the last load and reflect it by an
>   immediate which would equal the first store?

Access is defined in [[defns.access]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/defns.access#:access) to mean:

> read or modify the value of an object

So modifying the value via `*alias_to_array_s='Y';` is just as acceptable as reading it.

The compiler is allowed to optimize load/stores via the as-if rule. Your program doesn't have any observable behavior. If the assert passes, the compiler is free to replace `g()` with an empty body and not call it at all. If you are really worried about the compiler reordering the load/stores, you should be using `volatile` or look into memory barriers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [these](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) criteria, arrays are objects and objects can be inspected through `unsigned char` pointers and references. Let's break down your code.

Firstly, we declare an array of `unsigned char` of size 1.

```
unsigned char s[]={'X'};
```

We create a pointer to `unsigned char[1]`. This is the same type as `s` so we're fine.

```
unsigned char (*pointer_to_array_s)[1] = &s;
```

Now this is the tricky part. Your comment implies that the next conversion would make `alias_to_array_s` point to the first member of `s`, which is potentially UB. However, `s` is an object and its pointer can be `reinterpret_cast` to `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte` in order to inspect its representation. Therefore the next line is well defined as creating a pointer to the first byte of `s`'s representation.

```
unsigned char *alias_to_array_s = 
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pointer_to_array_s);
```

Your other example of modifying `s` through `alias_to_array_s` should also be fine, because you're modifying the first byte of the object's representation. In the case of `unsigned char[]` that is the first element. The important point here is that you did not convert a pointer-to-array to a pointer-to-first-element. You cast a pointer-to-array to `unsigned char *` to inspect its representation.