# Do we need to use std::launder when doing pointer arithmetic within a standard-layout object (e.g., with offsetof)?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, offsetof, stdlaunder

This question is a follow-up to: [Is adding to a "char *" pointer UB, when it doesn't actually point to a char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498585/is-adding-to-a-char-pointer-ub-when-it-doesnt-actually-point-to-a-char-arr)

In [CWG 1314](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1314), CWG affirmed that it is legal to perform pointer arithmetic within a standard-layout object using an `unsigned char` pointer. This would appear to imply that some code similar to that in the linked question should work as intended:

```
struct Foo {
    float x, y, z;
};

Foo f;
unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&f) + offsetof(Foo, z); // (*)
*reinterpret_cast<float*>(p) = 42.0f;
```

(I have replaced `char` with `unsigned char` for greater clarity.)

However, it seems that the new changes in C++17 imply that this code is now UB unless `std::launder` is used after both `reinterpret_cast`s. The result of a `reinterpret_cast` between two pointer types is equivalent to two `static_cast`s: the first to *cv* `void*`, the second to the destination pointer type. But [expr.static.cast]/13 implies that this produces a pointer to the original object, not to an object of the destination type, since an object of type `Foo` is not pointer-interconvertible with an `unsigned char` object at its first byte, nor is an `unsigned char` object at the first byte of `f.z` pointer-interconvertible with `f.z` itself.

I find it hard to believe that the committee intended a change that would break this very common idiom, making all pre-C++17 usages of `offsetof` undefined.

Comment: I would think that `p` is a pointer with the address of `f.z`, and since `f.z` is a float, using it through a `float*` would not violate strict aliasing (And all  standard layout object addresses are able to be stored as a `unsigned char*`, as this is the object representation)

Comment: @Artyer Strict aliasing is not the issue here. The strict aliasing rule existed before C++17, and `std::launder` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Brian: "*that this produces a pointer to the original object*" What "original object" are we talking about here? `p` doesn't point to a `Foo` anymore. It points to a byte. It stopped pointing to a `Foo` when you performed pointer arithmetic on a byte array pointer.

Comment: @NicolBolas [expr.static.cast]/13 seems to imply, with the wording "the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion", that `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&f)` still points to `f`, rather than to an `unsigned char` object at the beginning of `f`.

Comment: @Brian: But we're not talking about the result of that reinterpret cast; we're talking about the result of the *pointer arithmetic* of the byte pointer.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you have an `unsigned char*` whose value is a pointer to a `Foo` object (rather than a pointer to an `unsigned char` object), then it seems that doing pointer arithmetic using that pointer is illegal ([expr.add]/6). `std::launder` seems like it would fix this, by forcing the pointer to point to a `unsigned char` rather than a `Foo`.

Comment: @Brian: But CWG1314 you cited it, says otherwise. Nothing in C++17 changed either of those, so it's not clear what you're concerned about with regard to the arithmetic.

Comment: @NicolBolas C++17 appears to have changed the semantics of pointer values, so that now, `reinterpret_cast` no longer does what it used to do, unless there is a pointer-interconvertible object of the target type. Presumably, CWG 1314 still applies in the sense that once you already *have* a pointer to an `unsigned char` object, you can do arithmetic on it. But C++17 seems to change the requirements for obtaining that pointer value.

Comment: https://wg21.link/CWG1701. CWG doesn't seem to have discussed that issue recently, but the most recent discussion from a few years back do not appear to have a clear direction.

Comment: @T.C. So CWG changed its mind between 2011 and 2013? Any idea why?

Comment: `launder` won't help you, because it requires an object of `unsigned char` type to be alive at the address represented by the argument of `launder`

Comment: @LanguageLawyer the CWG1314 resolution affirms that every object can be considered to have an `unsigned char` object alive at each byte of it

Comment: @M.M there is no resolution of CWG1701 which reaffirms CWG1314 resolution. Also, your interpretation of CWG1314 resolution is not compatible with http://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#8

Comment: @LanguageLawyer CWG resolutions resolve issues with the standard , if something seems "not compatible" it means the committee says the standard was wrong or should be interpreted differently than you think

Comment: @M.M I'm not an expert here, but how I understand it: if wording incompatible with previous CWG resolutions (or conclusions from it) is added (that wording was added after the resolution, wasn't it?), this cancels those resolutions (or conclusions from it).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer in this case the resolution says that they think the wording already specifies what the resolution says and so no changes are needed

Comment: @M.M anyway, an object of `unsigned char` can't be alive at the first byte of another alive object (except for special cases like struct with the first member of `unsigned char` type etc.) per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#8

Comment: @LanguageLawyer according to the committee, you're reading intro.object#8 wrong and the unsigned char object is alive.

Comment: @M.M if [intro.object]/8 was added later than the resolution of CWG1314, it doesn't have to apply to [into.object]/8.

Answer (score 2):

**You question was:**

> Do we need to use std::launder when doing pointer arithmetic within a
>   standard-layout object (e.g., with offsetof)?

No.

`std::launder` won't change anything in this case and therefore has nothing to do with the presented example (*imo* edit launder out of the question or ask another question).

`std::launder` is usually just needed in a subset of cases (eg. due to a const member) where you change (or create) *an underlying object* in some *runtime* manner (eg. via placement new). Mnemonic: the object is 'dirty' and needs to be `std::launder`'ed.

**Using only a standard layout type cannot result in a situation where you would ever need to use std::launder.**

Comment: `size_t` should represent size of an object and may be not enough to represent a pointer. You should use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`.

Comment: The mapping from integral to pointer type is anyway implementation-defined, so whether your code will behave as expected is implementation-defined. In any case, I don't see how the answer relates to the question. There is no cast to integral type in the question.

Comment: @walnut it was a kind of proof by contradiction but I guess you are right. I updated the answer.